# WPF Global ResourceDictionary for application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to improve maintainability and consistency of my Windows App (c#, WPF, MVVM)

Currently in every Window/UserControl I am loading a ResourceDictionary for the App Style and Theme like this:

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Theming/ApplicationStyle.xaml" />
  </Window.Resources>
```

I am trying to make this something which is set globally rather than on a file level.

I read online that I should be able to declare the Resource Dictionary in an app.xaml file, but my application does not have this and if I try to add one I get an error:

[image: MyApp Build Error]

My Application has:

[image: App Solution Explorer]

Here is the basics of my app.csproj file:
[image: MyApp.csproj]

Is there a way I can define the resourceDictionary in the Program.cs or App.cs or is the a way around the error I am seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Your WPF application has also `App.xaml` file, and there you can arrange global resource dictionaries:

Example:

```
<Application
    x:Class="XXXXXXX"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YYYYYY"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    Startup="App_OnStartup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <materialDesign:BundledTheme
                    BaseTheme="Light"
                    PrimaryColor="Blue"
                    SecondaryColor="Lime" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/XamlFlair.WPF;component/DefaultAnimations.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: I cannot find any such app.xaml file.
I updated my question with a screenshot of Solution Explorer

Comment: I have never seen WPF app without `App.xaml` and `App.xaml.cs` files. What do you have in `.csproj` file?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the basics of the .csproj file to the Question. Thanks for your help